# Is it possible to proxy remote content on HTTPS page?

Tags: http, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

I would love to display a web page over HTTPS but sadly my business requires me to include external content via an iframe. I was wondering if it would be possible to use a (reverse)proxy or any other system, so the browser would not break the lock or even refuse to display it at all.

Thanks a lot for your help
Regards
Patrik

Comment: Couldn't quite follow the question. Is the external iframe over HTTP, and you're concerned about getting mixed content warning from the browser?

Comment: Hi RomanK, sorry for not being clear. Yes we do need to include Pages in iframe that are not able to be delivered in HTTPS so we would get a lot of mixed content warnings. Since we would love to have secure environment for our users we look for a solution to go about it.

Comment: Unless someone else chimes in, I can't see a solution to this. Even if you create an HTTPs reverse proxy, your certificate will have to be issued on the domain which the iframe is on, and presumably you do not own that domain and cannot create certificates for it.
Maybe you could self sign your cert and ask users to install your CA.

Answer (score 1):

In apache server you can use a proxy reverse like this:

```
<Location /newcontext>
    ProxyPass http://www.httpaddress.com/originalcontext
    ProxyPassReverse  http://www.httpaddress.com/originalcontext
</Location>
```

and access in your browser as https://yourserver/newcontext/

But if the original address must not reference other http resources then the resulting page will have mixed content